# Monitoring a file copy operation initiated from the command prompt

Tags: delphi

I want to monitor the copy file function using Delphi.

I can do it in windows explorer with shell notifier.

My problem is when copying file with the command prompt.

How can I monitor the progress of a copy file operation that has been initiated at the command prompt, using Delphi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally used these two:

- When using .NET, use the [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.
- When using Win32, use a combination of [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx), [FindNextChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364427(VS.85).aspx) and [FindCloseChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364414(VS.85).aspx).

Ah - just found out the Win32 portion of your question is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396905/detect-disk-activity-in-delphi), and that answer has a code example.

There is also [another Win32 way of doing this](http://www.osnews.com/story/7376/A_Directory_Monitor_Class_For_Delphi): using [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx), but I don't have personally used it.

Good luck!

--jeroen